# Can H2CO3 and NaHCO3 be in the same solution at the same time?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

In my opinion they can't. Because the product of reaction will have $\ce{H2CO3}$, and end up with $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{CO2(g)}$. And gas can not be part of a solution.

$$\ce{H2CO3 +2NaHCO3 -> Na2CO3 + 2H2O + 2CO2(g)}$$

Comment: Well, if you boiled it out and then heated the rest, you would end with Na2CO3(s), H2O(g) and CO2(g). Otherwise, turning drinking water with carbon dioxide/carbonic acid/bicarbonate pH buffer to washing soda solution  is not observed.

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.

Answer (score 2):

There are ongoing four linked equilibrium reactions with their respective equilibrium constants:

$$\ce{CO3^2-(aq) <=>[+H+][-H+]HCO3-(aq)<=>[+H+][-H+]H2CO3(aq)<=>[-H2O][+H2O]CO2(aq)<=>CO2(g)}$$

For drinking water with natural bicarbonate $\mathrm{pH}$ buffer, the concentrations of $\ce{HCO3-(aq)}$ and $\ce{CO2(aq)}$ are comparable, with minor concentration of $\ce{H2CO3(aq)}$. See also [carbonic acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonic_acid) on Wikipedia.